# Stacked bars of counts of the elements of one column organised by another column

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am having a hard time to produce a chart where counts of one feature are stacked per another feature.

Assume the dataframe below:

```
     method  year proteins  values       QC
0      John  2018        A      30     PASS
1      Kate  2018        B      11     PASS
2      Kate  2018        C      22  NO-PASS
3   Patrick  2019        A      60     PASS
4   Patrick  2019        B      40  NO-PASS
5   Patrick  2019        C      50  NO-PASS
6      Mary  2017        A       8  NO-PASS
7      Mary  2017        B      11     PASS
```

I have so far this: `(df['QC'].value_counts(dropna=True, normalize=True)*100).plot(kind='bar', rot=0, color='c', title='how many pass QC').set(xlabel="QC options", ylabel="% proteins")`which produces a basic bar plot of counts.

[image: pab plot of counts]

But I actually need each bar to be *"built by counts per protein"*, like the one below made with excel. I have tried by pivoting it as well, but then I do not have numerical data and I fail moving on from there.

[image: bar plot of counts per protein with excel]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas will plot each column as **bars** and stack them with the keyword **stacked=True**. So you have to calculate and reshape your data to fit this logic.

```py
# Get the #'s data points in the groups
gdf = df.groupby(['proteins', 'QC'])['values'].count()

# Normalize to 100.0
gdf = gdf.div(gdf.sum())*100.0

# Since we want to stack by protiens, lets make them columns
gdf = gdf.unstack('proteins')

# If you want to choose a subset of columns to plot
col_to_plot = gdf.columns.tolist()

# Plot command
gdf[col_to_plot].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Comment: Thanks... it makes so much better sense now how ```stacked``` works. I did not understand why you suggested to count the 'values'. I replaced the first line with this: ```gdf = df.groupby(['QC','proteins']).size()``` It results into the same thing.

Comment: There is no need to use `values` specifically. You are right to use **size**.